# Image::Magick module using with perl

Tags: perl

```
my $im = Image::Magick->new();
for my $image (@$imagedata) {
    $im->Read ($image);
}
my $tile = "1x";
my $output = $im->Montage (tile => $tile, geometry=>'135x50');
$output->Write("sprite_logos.png");
```

I have written above code ,I am getting as error "Can't locate object method "Write" via package "Exception 410: no images defined `Image::Magick'" (perhaps you forgot to load "Exception 410: no images defined`Image::Magick'"?) at logo_sprit.pl line 65."

When checked for issue after debugging.I found that this module is having some problem with images of type (41726.jpg?0.641405799749506&,85872.jpg)

Can Someone help me in this issue.

Comment: You haven't shown the most important detail: how is `$output` initialized?

Comment: I have added the remaining code snippet.Please look into this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems `Montage` returns an `Image::Magick` object on success, and string containing the exception otherwise. Check the success with

```
my $output = $im->Montage (tile => $tile, geometry=>'135x50');
die $output unless ref $output;

$output->Write($filename);
```

Similarly, you should check the output of the `Read` method - it should be empty on success. Otherwise, it contains the exception text.

Comment: it still giving "Exception 410: no images defined `Image::Magick' at logo_sprit.pl line 65."

Comment: @Codeshow: Yes, but you can't call methods on something that's not an object. Now it's time to figure out why the Montage call failed.

Comment: Try printing the return value of the `Read` method, too.

Comment: Is there any specific format that "Image::Magick" accepts as my images are in format "abc.jpg?0.987789&"

Comment: @Codeshow: What do you mean by "format"? What you show is a filename.

Comment: $VAR1 = [
          '/home/www/html/media-sea/hk/logos/swift_135x50.jpg?0.790242741085255&',
          '/home/www/html/media-sea/hk/logos/monster_160x60_border.gif?0.520726705307151&'
        ];
$VAR1 = bless( [], 'Image::Magick' );
Exception 410: no images defined `Image::Magick' at logo_sprit.pl line 65.

Comment: you can see my @$imagedata  has 2 images and output of Read method.

Comment: No, that's what $im contains, not what Read returns. `warn $im->Read(...)`

Comment: read bless[] is blank , it means Read method has not read my images.So, what I am asking is ,Does "Image::Magick " accepts only image of type "abc.jpg" or it can  accept "abc.jpg?0.98978&" format also. Or we need to pass some parameter to gert accepted such images format.

Comment: I don't know what format your images are in. As for the filename, my installation is able to read even filenames containing ? and &. The output of Read should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Exception 435: unable to open image `/home/www/html/images/logos/135x50.jpg?0.800537361135422&': No such file or directory

Comment: This is returned by Read method

Comment: So, now you know. What does `warn -e $image` output?